# AWS Lambda with Cognito right approach

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I would like to make a simple API available to a client. The client uses the output of my API within his application. The API is a pretty simple one. I'm deploying with the serverless framework to AWS Lambda. The functions exposed via the API don't use any other AWS services (like S3 etc).

My question is what kind of authentication to use. I was thinking to try to use cognito for this.

**1. Question:**
Does this make sense? Or is for this simple use case even an easier option available?

**2. Question:**
So I get this right. I would first create a user pool. Then create an identity pool based on this user pool?

**3. Question:**
At the end, my client gets the access token from cognito and attaches is to the header in the request. This gives him then access through API Gateway to my REST API and the lambda function is triggered. But how does the client in the first place can create an "account" doe the user pool? Am I involved i this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito Authentication does sound like a good option for this use-case. You can have a flow as follows:

`Cognito User Pool Authentication -> Token passed as header to the API in API Gateway -> API returns JSON data after successful authentication` 
[a].

I would like to emphasise that a Cognito User Pool is enough to satisfy this use-case. Cognito User Pools are used for Authentication, and Cognito Identity Pools are used for Authorization. Cognito Identity Pools essentially generates temporary AWS credentials, which are vended by AWS STS. Hence, I do not see where you would require Cognito Identity Pools here.

And to generate a JWT Token, you would need to have the user perform a successful authentication operation. To perform a successful authentication operation that returns tokens, you could have a look at the `InitiateAuth` API call[b].

## References

[a]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

[b]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html

Comment: many thanks for your answer. But one point is still not fully clear to me. If I set up a cognito user pool, how can I add the user there or invite him? The reference in [a] says: `the client must first sign the user in to the user pool, obtain an identity or access token for the user, and then call the API method with one of the tokens,` Does this mean he needs to register initially? Is AWS Coginito providing this. From my perspective all I care about is that API Gateway get the right bearer token in the authorization header.

Comment: @math You are indeed correct. Without Signing up and Signing in, you cannot obtain OIDC compliant ID and Access Tokens from Cognito.

Comment: Is this handled by cognito? I.e. does my client sign up to cognito user pool via a specific link or how does this exactly work? I'm just a bit confused of the steps from how the client can register to the pool and getting his access tokens. Sorry if this too specific. For me it is just important to know what I need to setup on my side and whats provided by AWS Cognito or needs to be done by the client

Comment: Basically, the user would sign-up. Then they sign-in. And then they get tokens. Those Tokens are passed in the REST API's Authorization header, and you can successfully access whatever Lambda returns back.

Comment: But just one last question. Since I have only the API up and running and not a web application with a frontend. How does the original signup / sign in work?

Comment: You could either use the Cognito Hosted UI, or an API call like [Initiate Auth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html). However, kindly note that when you are using APIs, the flow does not follow the OAuth 2.0 conventions. 
Now, it is up to you and your business requirements to decide on what would be the best.